# Scala - trouble with type inference in lambda expression

Tags: scala, lambda, type-conversion

Attempting to compile the function below in scala 2.11.0

```
def dafuq(canvas: Array[Array[Boolean]]): Array[Array[Boolean]] = {
        for (r <- canvas.reverse) yield r.zipWithIndex.map((c: Boolean, i: Int) => c) 
}
```

yields

```
Solution.scala:6: error: type mismatch;
   found   : (Boolean, Int) => Boolean
   required: ((Boolean, Int)) => ?
        for (r <- canvas.reverse) yield r.zipWithIndex.map((c: Boolean, i: Int) => c) 
                                                                                ^
```

The function is bogus but it illustrates a problem that I have encountered. I'm quite new to Scala so this could be a rookies mistake but I cannot find any solution or explanation to this problem. Do you know what causes the above behaviour?

Also is return type hinting possible for lambda expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this compile error many times too, but it's not a type inference issue. You supplied an anonymous function with 2 arguments, but the compiler expected a function with a single tuple argument. 2 solutions:

```
def dafuq(canvas: Array[Array[Boolean]]): Array[Array[Boolean]] = {
        for (r <- canvas.reverse) yield r.zipWithIndex.map(ci => ci._1)
}
```

or

```
def dafuq(canvas: Array[Array[Boolean]]): Array[Array[Boolean]] = {
        for (r <- canvas.reverse) yield r.zipWithIndex.map { case (c, i) => c }
}
```

In the first solution `ci` is inferred to a pair `(Boolean, Int)`. In the second solution we use a pattern match expression.

> Also is return type hinting possible for lambda expressions?

I don't know, but you can add type annotations on any expression. For example: `case (c, i) => c: Boolean`.

Comment: The second snippet uses a pattern match expression to define a function. It isn't a `PartialFunction`; it's a `Function1` (and it isn't partial, as it's defined over its entire domain). [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) section 8.5 specifies that a pattern match expression desugars to either `FunctionN` or `PartialFunction` depending on the context. In this case, since `map` expects a `Function1`, that's what it is.

Comment: I only know this because someone else has corrected me on stackoverflow before, so... keep passing it along :)